# JavaFX Tabs and Controller Scope

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx-8

I have a configurations pane in my JavaFX 8 application that is spread across a number of tabs within tabs. Currently I am forced to split tabs for a longer configuration process.

I know that I'll have two .fxml files for the two tabs, but I should be able to use the same controller for both. Currently, however, if I make changes to one tab, the other tab doesn't see the changes. I'm guessing it creates a separate instance of the controller. Is it possible for the two .fxml tabs to use the same instance of the controller so that the information can be shared across the two tabs?

Example for more clarification:
Tab1 contains textfield input for email, Firstname, etc.
Tab2 uses email information and generates usernames and allows user to modify other settings using the generated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reuse a controller between multiple FXML loads, you can use [fxmlLoader.setController()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setController-java.lang.Object-) or [fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory()](http://setControllerFactory(Callback%3CClass%3C?%3E,Object%3E%20controllerFactory)).

I don't really recommend a reused controller approach, so I won't post detailed code for it here.  Rather, I recommend [passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml).